# How to change css style for only one image in specific page in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

For all the images by default the below style class is being set.

```
.figure {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I am trying to change `display: inline-block to display:inherit` only on a particular page. I added the image via visual composer in WP,and tried adding a new class for the image div by adding the style needed, but still the display:inline-block remained the same.Any solutions will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `!important` at the end of the value of the display in the new class?

Comment: try adding `display:inherit!important`

Comment: yes i added,but still it didn't work.

Comment: Could you send the link?

Comment: pax is the new class i have given.

Comment: Where is the `pax` class, I can't see it in your URL?

Comment: pax is seen in the div,but i couldn't see the mentioned style in css of inspect element,so that means the style is not getting in the page right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've added a custom style to the figure (you mentioned a `.pax` class), then you simply need to specify the following in the CSS:

```
.figure.pax{
  display:inherit;
}
```

If that doesnt work, you can either add specificity to the selector (my preference) or add `!important` as follows:

```
.figure.pax{
  display:inherit !important;
}
```

(Alternatively, if you'd like the image to be `display:block` which is what it looks like you'd like, use `display:block` instead of `display:inherit`)

Comment: @sa-7 - Excellent, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

please add inline css and check its working or not?

If its working then add new class and add that class end of the css and try it will work

Like add `inline-img` this is the new class then add following css to end of your css file

```
.figure.inline-img{
 display:inherit;
}
```

Comment: When i add the style on inspect element it's working,but when i write in style sheet and add the class it's not working,will that be a problem with my stylesheet?

Comment: Yes the problem is with the stylesheet loading order when you want to overwrite the existing css class then you need to include at last.

Comment: In which CSS you have `.figure` class and in which Css you have added new `.figure.inline-img` class?

Comment: ohh... the .figure is in theme.css,and i added the new class in style.css via the editor.

Comment: Please add the in theme.css at end of the file.